# Need to Bring up iOS keyboard on Page Load jQuery Select2 Question

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ios, jquery-select2

Tried `$('#id').select2('open');` but iOS keyboard doesn't pop up. Also tried focus but having the same issue.

Here's a JSFiddle of my example. https://jsfiddle.net/nstruth/ujpzn1ma/1/

Please help. Thanks